# integrating angular 6 component into angularjs template

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade

I am trying to integrate Angular 6 component into AngularJs template. What I am working on is not root application. It is used as library for the root application. I have created the app.ts like below.

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { downgradeComponent } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { TestComponent } from './test.component';

export const angularjsModule = angular.module('angularjs-module', [
    'angularjs.directives'
]).directive('testComponent', downgradeComponent({
    component: TestComponent
}) );

@NgModule({
        declarations: [
            TestComponent
        ],
        imports: [
            BrowserAnimationsModule,
            BrowserModule,
            CommonModule,
            UpgradeModule
        ],
        exports: [
        ],
        providers: [
        ],
        bootstrap: [],
        entryComponents: [TestComponent]
    })

    export class AngularModule{}
```

With above app.ts, I added TestComponent () into angularjs template. The TestComponent is very simple component which has only one div element. But I do not see the TestComponent is integrated into angularjs directive in the developer tool. As far as I feel, I have read https://angular.io/guide/upgrade carefully. And I think once I register the TestComponent into NgModule, it should be incorporated into app properly, but it turns out to be not. If anyone has similar experience, can you share it? If you need more information, I can add as much information as possible.

I have run into the following error, did anyone experience the same situation? :)

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate 
module $$UpgradeModule due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ng.shell.main due 
to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ort due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module undefined due to:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'module' is not a function, got undefined
```

Comment: If you see the code above, there is a downgrading part, downgradeComponent.

Comment: I do not think we really need to use downgradeModule, i have different library to downgrade angular component to angularjs directive with the exactly same way without any issue. My understanding is injector does not work properly, angularjs has rootInjector.. anyway there must be something wrong because I got the error above.

Comment: Have you found the solution?